# Problema con DELETE de CRUD

Tags: mysql, angular, typescript, spring-boot

estoy haciendo el crud para mi proyecto pero al momento de hacer el metodo DELETE quiero usar la propiedad filter para poder filtrar el id y asi poder borrar la entrada, pero me dice:
*La propiedad "filter" no existe en el tipo 'expe'*
ya probe importar la propiedad desde rxjs/operators desde app.component.ts, app.routing.ts y hasta del servicio pero sigue igual, alguien sabe de donde viene este error?

**Este es el ts del componente**

```html
import { edu } from './../../model/edu';
import { PorfolioService } from './../../services/porfolio.service';
import { expe } from './../../model/expe';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from '../../services/auth.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-editor',
  templateUrl: './editor.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./editor.component.css']
})
export class EditorComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private auth:AuthService, private router: Router, private service:PorfolioService) { }

  exper:expe = new expe();
  educ:edu = new edu();
  experiencia: expe[];
  educacion : edu[];

  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.EditarExpe();
    this.EditarEdu();

    this.service.getExpe()
    .subscribe(data =>{
      this.experiencia=data;
    });

    this.service.getEdu()
    .subscribe(data =>{
      this.educacion=data;
    })

  }
DeleteExpe(exper: expe){
    this.service.deleteExpe(exper)
    .subscribe(data=>{
      this.exper=this.exper.filter(e=>e!==exper);
      alert("Usuario eliminado...");
    })
```

**Este es el servicio**

```html
import { edu } from './../model/edu';
import { expe } from './../model/expe';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PorfolioService {

  constructor( private http:HttpClient) { }

  Urlexpe='http://localhost:8080/proyecto_ap/elemento';
  Urledu='http://localhost:8080/proyecto_ap/estudio';

  getExpe(){
    return this.http.get<expe[]>(this.Urlexpe);
  }
  creaExpe(exper:expe){ 
    return this.http.post<expe>(this.Urlexpe, exper);
  }

  getEdu(){
    return this.http.get<edu[]>(this.Urledu);
  }
  creaEdu(educ:edu){ 
    return this.http.post<edu>(this.Urledu, educ);
  }

  updateExpe(exper: expe){
    return this.http.put<expe>(this.Urlexpe + "/" + exper.id, exper);
  }

  deleteExpe(exper: expe){
    return this.http.delete<expe>(this.Urlexpe + "/" + exper.id);
  }

  getExpeId(id:number){
    return this.http.get<expe>(this.Urlexpe + "/" + id);
  }

  getEducId(id:number){
    return this.http.get<edu>(this.Urledu + "/" + id);
  }

  updateEdu(educ: edu){
    return this.http.put<edu>(this.Urledu + "/" + educ.id, educ);
  }
  deleteEdu(educ: edu){
    return this.http.delete<edu>(this.Urledu + "/" + educ.id);
  }

  obtenerDatos():Observable<any>{
    return this.http.get('./assets/data/data.json');
  }
}
```

**Y este es el objeto modelo**

```html
export class expe{

    constructor(){}

    id:number;
    titulo:String;
    seccion:String;
    descripcion:String;

}
```

nose si me falta importar alguna dependencia mas o solo seria declarar algo mas!

Comment: `this.expe` es un objeto no un arreglo por eso no funciona el `filter`.

Comment: y como podria filtrar el id? sacando el constructor?

Comment: En lugar `this.exper` usa `this.experiencia` ese el arreglo al que se le debe remover el elemento eliminado.

Answer (score 0):

En tu función ***DeleteExpe*** estás recibiendo toda la data a través de exper. Entonces, podrías hacer algo similar a:

```
DeleteExpe(exper: expe){
    this.service.deleteExpe(exper.id)
    .subscribe(data=>{
      console.log("Response recibida de la operación: ", data);
      // if (data.code == 200) alert("Usuario eliminado...");
    })
```

La operación CRUD va del lado backend. Si deseas usar el *suscribe* debes registrarte a un observable

```
deleteExpe(id: number): Observable<expe> {
    return this.http.delete<expe>(this.Urlexpe + "/" + id);
  }
```

Como consejo para el nombre de tu model deberías usar camelCase: Ex: NombreDeLaClase